# How can I delete every file but one extension

Tags: regex, linux, bash, delete-file, rm

I have a folder which contains some extension of file, I want to remove all but html extension. Can any one help me?

Comment: @jmetz: Not so good accepted solution of that question.

Comment: @anubhava: The question is still a duplicate, and the answers contain all the answers given here so far. The voting is up to the users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `bash`'s extglob feature. To enable it, if it's not already on:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then you can simply negate the glob:

```
rm !(*.html)
```

Comment: Found a good article on extended globbing in bash - http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing

Comment: a new way here: `$ find . -type f ! -name '*.html' -delete`

Answer (score 7):

You can use this find command:

```
find /your/path -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.html' -delete
```

Comment: Neither is `"*.html"`.

Comment: I believe in find command it doesn't matter to use single quote or double quote but still I edited.

Comment: Might want to limit yourself to files with `-type f`. Moreover, such a negative match can be dangerous with `find` since `.` is matched!

Comment: Thanks @gniourf_gniourf, it is fixed.

Comment: the `-a` is useless `:D`.

Comment: Have to admit I was wrong